# Backbone with underscore template example

Tags: html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am new to backbonejs and underscorejs. I found some [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6pBvMK1Qgo) materials on to watch and I faced problem when tried to modify example.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head >
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/backbone.js"></script>

    <script type="text/template" id="list-template">
      <li><a href="<%= href %>"><%= text %></a></li>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">


        model = new Backbone.Model({
            data: [
                {text: "Google", href: "google.com"},
                {text: "Facebook", href: "facebook.com"},
                {text: "Yahoo", href: "yahoo.com"}
            ]
        });


        var View = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: "#container",
            events: {
                "click button": "render"
            },
            render: function(){
                var data = this.model.get('data');
                for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
                    var variables = { href: data[i].href, text: data[i].text };
                    var li = _.template( $("#list-template").html(), variables );
                    this.$el.find('ul').append(li);
                }
            }
        });

        var view = new View({ model: model });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <button>Load</button>
        <ul id="list">
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

It of course does not work and I am failing to find the cause. If you see please answer or guide on how to bind template on custom event rather then initialize.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Lukas No errors at all(also monitoring Firefox console)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the JavaScript is executing before the elements have been rendered on the page. Wrap your code in `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var model = new Backbone.Model({
    ....
    var view = new View({ model: model });
});
```

Comment: The view has  el: "#container" hardcoded, doesn't this ensure presence of element in view? I have just tried, still does not work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the video that is not using underscore.js templeting there is no $(document).ready(function() also on this link http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/ they do not use it. What is the trick? Thanks again.

Comment: The trick is that in the example you've linked to, the JavaScript is placed in a `<script type="text/javascript></script>` AFTER the HTML code.

Comment: (See this comment from the article: "I think it's worth pointing out the reason that the search container div is defined before the script. If it is defined afterwards then the javascript will execute before that HTML element exists and nothing will be rendered.")